# AWS SDK - Search for images by partial name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to start an ec2 instance via the java sdk.I always want to get the 'latest' Windows Server 2019 ami. At the moment we hard code the image id. I can make a describe image request like below:

```
DescribeImagesRequest request = new DescribeImagesRequest().withFilters(new LinkedList<Filter>())
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("name").withValues("Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-2020.05.13"))
DescribeImagesResult describeImagesResult= getAmazonEc2Client().describeImages(request)
List<Image> images = describeImagesResult.getImages()
return images[0].getImageId()
```

Of course this returns one image id, because of the unique name. I effectively want to search for 'Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base' and then find the one that's latest. Searching in the UI returns 8 community images; 4 start with 'Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base' and provided by Amazon. How do I get all 8 back? (I can then wittle down to ones that start with 'Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base' and then sort by name to get latest one)

I tried searching for 'Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base' and 'Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base%' but both return 0 results via the api...

(Filter details are at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/EC2/Types/DescribeImagesRequest.html)

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest Windows Server AMI, you are better off using Parameter Store:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-for-the-latest-windows-ami-using-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Note you can also get the latest Amazon Linux AMI via similar methods:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/